# I am using a img url from one website in my app. Some people gets reCaptcha

Tags: javascript, image, recaptcha

In my Chrome Extension, I render some images from one website.
One image source is like this: https://fmdataba.com/images/p/8583.png

Some people cannot render the image properly

[image]

When they access the image address, they get a reCaptcha checking whether they are automated bots or not.

This is really weird to me since some of them can access it toally fine while some cannot.

Is there a reason for this happening and are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the image headers, you'll see

> server: cloudflare

That domain likely has Cloudflare's scrape shield function enabled.

https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-scrapeshield-discover-defend-dete/

Comment: Is there any way to avoid it? It's weird because the reCaptcha only shows up for some ppl.